# How do I manage the value of multiple radio buttons with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, radio-button

I have an array that comes from an API, and I've set up several questions on the frontend, and the answers are the same for each question.

I wanted to know how I:

1. Get the value of each question in a single send button (Object that will be sent to API).
2. Set a default value for each of the questions.

The example I want to reproduce is similar to what is written here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiz-app-testing-oox9dk?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import { Questions } from "./components/Questions";

import { questions } from "./data_store/questions";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={() => {}}>
        {questions.map(({ id, asking, answers }) => (
          <Questions id={id} asking={asking} answers={answers} />
        ))}

        <br />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Component Question:

```
interface QuestionsProps {
  id: string;
  asking: string;
  answers: string[];
}

export function Questions({ id, asking, answers }: QuestionsProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{asking}</p>
      {answers.map((value) => (
        <label htmlFor={id}>
          {value}
          <input type="radio" name={id} value={value} />
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Question array:

```
const answers = ["C", "NC", "NA", "NO", "R"];

export const questions = [
  {
    id: "1",
    asking: "Question 1?",
    answers
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    asking: "Question 2?",
    answers
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    asking: "Question 3?",
    answers
  }
];
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by managing all of the answers in state using an object. You didn't provide any code so it's hard to give more accurate help but it should look like something along these lines:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({
  answerA: 'a',
  answerB: 'a',
  answerC: 'a',
})
```

Then using radio inputs and `onChange` handler you will manage when the state changes and what it changes to which might look like this for every question:

```
<input
  type="radio"
  id="a"
  name="question-a-answer-a"
  value="a"
  onChange={(e) => setAnswers({
    ...answers,
    answerA: e.target.value,
  })}
  checked={answers.answerA === 'a'}
>
<label for="a">A</label>

<input
  type="radio"
  id="b"
  name="question-a-answer-b"
  value="b"
  onChange={(e) => setAnswers({
    ...answers,
    answerA: e.target.value,
  })}
  checked={answers.answerA === 'b'}
>
<label for="b">B</label>

and so on...
```

Comment: I left an example code in the codesandbox link in the question. This link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiz-app-testing-oox9dk?file=/src/App.tsx . In it, there is the example that I intend to reproduce.